# I'm stuck in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I'm stuck in the VirtualBox terminal `Fatal:No bootable medium found! System halted`. Is there a shortcut key to close? What do I do to close it?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: The version i doesnt know,i use on the virtual box 64 bit but i doesnt chosse de version

Comment: Well since you do not know the most basic thing about your system I do not think any one can help you.

Comment: Thanks guys, but I've already solve it

Answer (score 0):

If your mouse pointer is not captured by the host OS, just press the `right Ctrl or Control` key to exit from the VM.

Then, File menu -> Close to shut down the VM